# how to get selected item from a custom bottomNavBar in android

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I am working on my custom **bottomNavigationBar** by extending the view class , everything is working very well, i made a method to get the selected item from my customView ,but when i try to get in in my MainActivity it doesn't work.

This is my BottomNavBar class :

```
public class BottomNavBar extends View
{
    private RectF outerRect;
    private Rect[] items;
    private Paint outerPaint,shadowPaint,itemPaint,itemClickedPaint,itemCutPaint;
    private Path outerPath;
    private int width,height;
    private float[] outerRadii={50,50,50,50,50,50,50,50},circle={60,60,60,60,60,60,60,60};
    private Drawable[] icon;
    private ArrayList<Integer> iconsList;
    private int outerShapeColor,itemCircleColor;
    private int itemClickedCount=0;
    private long pressStartTime,pressDuration;
    private int clickXpos,clickYpos;
    public boolean itemClicked,click,longPress;
    private bottomBarSet set;
    public BottomNavBar (Context context) {super(context);}
    public BottomNavBar(Context context , AttributeSet attr) {super(context, attr);}

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        this.getLayoutParams().width=getWidth();
        this.getLayoutParams().height=120;
        this.setLayoutParams(this.getLayoutParams());
        int xPos=getLeft()+50;
        int yPos=getHeight() -110;
        width=getMeasuredWidth()-50;
        height=100;
        drawOuterShape(canvas,xPos,yPos,width,height);
        drawItems(canvas,xPos,yPos);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    private void drawOuterShape(Canvas canvas, float xPos,float yPos, float width ,float height)
    {
        outerRect =new RectF(xPos,yPos,width,height);
        shadowPaint=new Paint();
        shadowPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        shadowPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(15,BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
        shadowPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#181818"));
        shadowPaint.setAlpha(80);
        
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
            setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }
        outerPaint=new Paint();
        outerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        outerPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        outerPaint.setColor(outerShapeColor);

        outerPath =new Path();
        outerPath.addRoundRect(xPos-5,yPos+10,width+5,height+10,outerRadii,Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.drawPath(outerPath,shadowPaint);
        outerPath.reset();
        outerPath.addRoundRect(outerRect,outerRadii,Path.Direction.CW);
        canvas.drawPath(outerPath,outerPaint);
    }

    private void drawItems(Canvas canvas,int Xpos,int Ypos)
    {
//init paint 
        itemPaint =new Paint();
        itemPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        itemPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        itemPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        items=new Rect[4];

        
        int itemWidth=(width-50)/items.length;
        for(int i=0;i<items.length;i++){
            int startLeft=Xpos;
            int itemLeft =startLeft +(i*itemWidth);
            int itemTop = Ypos;
            int itemRight=startLeft+((i+1)*itemWidth);
            int itemBottom=height;

            items[i] =new Rect(itemLeft,itemTop,itemRight,itemBottom);
            Path path=new Path();
            //draw item
            
            RectF[] rect=new RectF[4];
            rect[i] =new RectF();
            rect[i].set(items[i]);

            path.addRoundRect(rect[i],circle,Path.Direction.CW);
            canvas.drawPath(path,itemPaint);
            //draw clicked item
            if(i==itemClickedCount){
                itemClickedPaint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
                itemClickedPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                itemClickedPaint.setColor(itemCircleColor);
                path.reset();
            
                path.addRoundRect(itemLeft-5,itemTop-5,itemRight+5,itemBottom+5,circle,Path.Direction.CW);
                canvas.drawPath(path,itemClickedPaint);
                itemCutPaint=new Paint();
                itemCutPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
                itemCutPaint.setAlpha(0);
                itemCutPaint.setColor(0xFFFFFF);
                itemCutPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                itemCutPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                
                path.reset();
                //path.addCircle(items[i].centerX(),items[i].centerY(),35,Path.Direction.CW);
                path.addRoundRect(itemLeft+10,itemTop+10,itemRight-10,itemBottom-10,circle,Path.Direction.CW);
                canvas.drawPath(path,itemCutPaint);
                
                //Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Count: "+ i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //check click item
            if(items[i].contains(clickXpos,clickYpos)) {
                itemClicked=true;
                final Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            
                            itemClicked=false;

                        }
                    }, 5);

            } else {itemClicked=false;}

            if(itemClicked==true){
                
                itemClickedCount=i;
                
                
            }
            


            //draw icon

            icon=new Drawable[4];
            icon[i]=getContext().getResources().getDrawable(iconsList.get(i));
            if(icon[i]!=null){
                
                icon[i].setBounds(items[i].centerX()-30,items[i].centerY()-30,items[i].centerX() +30,items[i].centerY()+30);
                icon[i].draw(canvas);
            }
            else{
                
                icon[i]=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_delete);
                icon[i].setBounds(items[i].centerX()-30,items[i].centerY()-30,items[i].centerX() +30,items[i].centerY()+30);

                icon[i].draw(canvas);
            }
            
        
            
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                pressStartTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                clickXpos=(int)event.getX();
                clickYpos=(int)event.getY();

                return true;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                pressDuration=System.currentTimeMillis()-pressStartTime;
                if(pressDuration<500 && distance(clickXpos,clickYpos,event.getX(),event.getY())<15){
                    // duration less than half second and distance less than 15 PXs
                    click=true;
                    longPress=false;
                    
                    //clicked
                }
                if(pressDuration>=1000 && distance(clickXpos,clickYpos,event.getX(),event.getY())<15){
                    // duration greater than 1 second and distance less than 15 PXs
                    click=false;
                    longPress=true;
                    
                    //long press
                }

                invalidate();
                return true;
            default :
                return super.onTouchEvent(event);



        }

        // TODO: Implement this method
    }

    private static float distance(float x1,float y1,float x2,float y2)
    {
        float dx = x1 - x2;
        float dy = y1 - y2;
        float distanceInPx = (float) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return distanceInPx;
    }
    
    
    //Setters
    
    public void setOuterShapeColor(int color){
        this.outerShapeColor=color;
    }
    public void setItemCircleColor(int color){
        this.itemCircleColor=color;
    }
    public void setIcons(ArrayList<Integer> icons){
        this.iconsList=icons;
    }

    //Getters
    
    public int getSelectedItem(){
        return itemClickedCount;
    }
    public boolean isClicked(){
        return itemClicked;
    }
    
    
    
    
    


}
```

When i add a Toast inside DrawItem() shows the selected item count successfully.
I tried to do a Listener for items and it didn't work too
Please help me guys and thanks .